# train SVM with MFCC

Tags: python, speech-recognition, svm

I have implemented some code where I extract mfcc's for 10 distinct wav files, each having an utterances of a digit multiple times.

I managed to create a GMM but I wanted to experiment with SVM as well. The testing are separate wav files.

My question is - I have the MFCC features of the 10 distinct wav files. How can I feed them to the SVM classifier?

this is the code I used to extract the features for each wav file:

```
def extract_feat(audio, rate):
    mfcc_feat = mfcc(audio, rate)
    #standardizing the features
    mfcc_feat = preprocessing.scale(mfcc_feat)
    #calculating the delta and double delta
    delta_one = delta(mfcc_feat,2)
    delta_two = delta(delta_one,2)
    combined = np.hstack([mfcc_feat,delta_one, delta_two]) 
    return combined

def createTrainingGMM(path):    
#iterating through the training file and getting all wav files to train GMM
for filename in glob.glob(path):
    #getting the sample rate value: 16000hz and the data read from wav file
    sr_value, x_value = wav.read(filename)
    #calling extract_feat which returns 39 mfcc features for each value in the vector
    vector = extract_feat(x_value, sr_value)#default values
```

How do I do something similar for SVM?

Comment: Please show an example of your dataset. You want to use your MFCCs as features and predict which of the 10 digits is being spoken?

Comment: What's the shape of each preprocessed wav? I suppose they also have a time axis. If you want to be simple, you can compute the mean of the MFCCs over time and feed this to an SVM classififer. You can also stack the means of the trained GMMs and used them as features. This is very common in speaker verification, but I don't know if it's gonna in your case.